# Facebook pages "recommendations"

Tags: facebook-pages

I am one of the administrators of a non-profit's FB page. Is it possible to delete, disable or turn off the "Recommendations" section of the page? If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

The "recommendations" section on Facebook Pages is enabled/disabled by [adding/removing the map address for your business](https://www.jonloomer.com/2012/09/25/facebook-page-recommendations/).

No one seems to know just *why* FB tied these two functionalities together, but to get rid of the "recommendations", you just need to remove the map display. From [this quora question/answer](http://www.quora.com/Facebook-Pages/Can-Recommendations-be-disabled-on-Facebook-Pages/comment/303523)

- Go to Page Settings -> Basic Information
- Uncheck "Show this map" under "Location Info"